# cannot get rigify rig to bind to mesh

Tags: animation, rigging

I am trying to animate a pony. I have a bunch of weight groups for fur. I am trying to bind the rigify rig to the mesh just to make sure that everything is working before I move on into more advanced rigging setups for inverse kinematics and xmuscle systems. However, I cannot get the rig to bind with with the mesh, nor can I get the bones to bind with the mesh. Here is a link to the file if anyone can figure it out. I would greatly appreciate it!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cjkv4yr6dkjk3it/test.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I checked it, first problem, you have your rig parented manually with your mesh, when you try to use "Parent with empty or automatic weights (or other algorithm) you have to have your mesh and armature without any parent/child relation, so you have to delete the parenting.
Now you will be able to parent your mesh to your armature (first select your mesh, then your armature and use parent) manually painting the vertex, only manually, why? Because you have duplicated vertexes and [non-manifold topology](http://transmagic.com/what-is-non-manifold-geometry/).
If you want to use automatic weight paint you have to clean your mesh first.

Any further questions, don't hesitate to ask me.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But, I do not think that it is working. I deleted 11 overlapping faces. I deleted all of the parents. I then clicked on both the bones and the mesh and clicked parent to object. I also generated a rig and parented that to the object in the same manner. It is still not binding to the mesh at all. I started a new vertex group for it, but it really does not matter because it will not bind.

Comment: I tried an armature modifier and clicked the deform box in the rig properties. Using the armature on the mesh and then giving the vertex group the same name as the rig and that did bind the rig to the mesh. However, as soon as I go into edit or pose mode it breaks away from the mesh and I cannot do anything.

Comment: So one person on CGTalk said that Rigify is broken and should not be used. He said to rig with individual bones. So that is what I did along with a modifier, except on a dummy mesh where I took four cubes and unioned them together. Then I put one bone going up per each cube.

Comment: Pt2 Then added an armature modifier to the cube and the clicked the mesh then bones and parented the object to an empty weight group. It created a new weight group called bone which I plugged into the modifier. It was progress and I think it will work on my pony so long as I can get one thing figured out. Only the third bone going up will move the mesh. The rest just leave it in pose mode. Here is a link to the test file https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6s51oe5mk2o4w4/test1.blend?dl=0

Comment: Because I need to be able to move bones that are not connected to each other that pose facial expressions. However, right now this does not seem possible because of the problem in my most recent post.

Comment: So now I figured out that the only way that I can get each bone to animate, is if they each have their own modifier. Does anyone know how to merge vertex groups so that I only have to use one modifier? I tried merging the bones in edit mode and they are all joined from object mode. But, that did not seem to do anything.

Comment: So right now all I can think of is going through each individual bone and giving it its own armature modifier and painting its own vertex group for where the bone is at respectively. Then applying the modifier after mixing it in with a vertex weight paint mix modifier to the sole armature modifier that I must leave active in order for the mesh to stay rigged. It is a rather elaborate process and if anyone has any ideas on how to make it faster I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: And I found out that Rigify does work, I think maybe I just had to restart my computer and is faster and more efficient than regular bones because you can always add to the rig. It is just that it is creating vertex groups with nothing in it and it is going to be a huge pain to go through each vertex group and locate each deformation bone and weight paint it. On the tutorials, most people seem to be only applying paint to one vertex group. That is just crazy. There are so many bones.

Comment: The best way that I can see it is to rig with individual bones so that you can name you own bones and then put them all into a collection group so that you can see which one is which when you have to go and paint all of those vertex groups.  The rigify rigs are so simple, it would be so nice to have a faster way of painting the vertex group. For an advanced rig there are going to be alot of bones.

Answer (score 0):

So I have reached the conclusion that what I needed to do was restart my computer as just some random bug was preventing the bones from parenting. Going through by individual bones and extruding them for more armature in edit mode is the best way to do it. There is no better way. Having a faster weight paint system over one vertex group for animating would not be logical and it would not make it possible to animate anything advanced that something good in satire would need to be. And it stays organized in the manner which it was created and from that order you can name each bone. Wherein, they highlight when you select them as you are going through weight paint mode when you have the in front option for the viewport checked on for the bones.